# Spring Interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate, interceptor, intercept

I need to create an interceptor that will intercept HTTP requests and responses, but it seems to me that I'm doing something wrong, can someone tell me what I should change or add?

```
public class HttpInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor
{
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(final HttpRequest httpRequest, final byte[] bytes, final ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException
    {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final ClientHttpResponse response = clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
        final String httpResponseName = response.toString();

        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = response.getHeaders();
        final HttpStatus httpStatusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        final String statusText = response.getStatusText();

        final String body = httpHeaders.toString() + httpStatusCode.toString() + statusText;
        //And then i will put body to DB

        return response;
    }
```

xml

```
<bean id="httpInterceptor" class="HttpInterceptor"/>
<bean id="httpInterceptor" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorMapping">
    <property name="interceptor" ref="httpInterceptor"/>
    <property name="typeCode" value="Message"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.  RestTemplate and ClientHttpRequestInterceptor are about outbound requests with your code as a client. ServiceLayer interceptors (see the XML) are about internal Hybris operations while processing requests (or other work).  Are you trying to capture inbound request details here, where an external system calls into Hybris?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you try to create service (it can be rest, soap or any other). If I am right, you need to create controller for handling http request.

```
@Controller("MyController")
public class MyController extends AbstractController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mymethod/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void myMethod(@PathVariable final String id, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse out) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id))
            throw new UnknownIdentifierException("id is null!");
        out.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_TXT_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(myStream, out.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownIdentifierException ex) {
        out.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        out.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        String message = "My error text!";
        IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes()), out.getOutputStream());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommande to implements Filter  to transform or use the information contained in the requests or responses. and not Interceptor , it provide more information then Interceptor Here's an exemple of the use of Filter for logging :

```
@Component
public class HttpLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpLoggingFilter.class);

    @Value("${output.trace.actif}")
    private boolean isOutputActif;

    private static String getRequestData(final HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String payload = null;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                payload = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
            }
        }
        return payload;
    }

    private static String getResponseData(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String payload = null;
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                payload = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                wrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
            }
        }
        return payload;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        logger.info("start http filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseToCache = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

        HttpUtil.majMDCRestInfo(httpServletRequest);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        chain.doFilter(requestToCache, responseToCache);

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        String requestBody = new String(requestToCache.getContentAsByteArray());
        String responseBody = new String(responseToCache.getContentAsByteArray());

        final StringBuilder logMessage = new StringBuilder().append("[METHOD:").append(httpServletRequest.getMethod())
                .append("] [PARAMS:")
                .append(httpServletRequest.getQueryString()).append("] [BODY:").append(requestBody).append("]");

        if (isOutputActif) {
            String respContent = responseBody;
            if (respContent.equals("")) {
                respContent = "no data";
            }
            logMessage.append(" [RESPONSE:").append(respContent).append("]");
        }

        logMessage.append(" [STATUS:").append(responseToCache.getStatus()).append("] [Time:").append(elapsedTime).append("ms]");
        String[] nonLoggingPaths = {"/api/"};
        String urlPath = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
        if ((Arrays.stream(nonLoggingPaths).parallel().anyMatch(urlPath::contains))) {
            logger.info("{}", logMessage);
        }

        getRequestData(requestToCache);
        getResponseData(responseToCache);
    }

}
```